# Two login systems in the same Flask application

Tags: flask, flask-login

I want to have two login systems in the same application. There is main site for the 'owners', the owners can have 'portals'. Each portal will have his own login system, this time for the 'users'. Users within the portal will have roles (admin, editor, etc).

Something like:

```
site.com -> owners loging
site.com/portal1 -> users login
site.com/portal2 -> other users login
```

Owners and users are stored in different tables.

I dont know how to achive this with Flask-Login. **How should I proceed?**

Other alternatives I'm thinking are:

- Split this application in two, one for the main site and the other
  one for portals.
- Join users and owners in the same table, and make the distiction if the user is owner or not. This I think is not desired, because they have different attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party frameworks to handle authentication in your application. I use [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) and have nothing to complain. They are really simple to use and have integration with Flask.

From their home page:

> *Add authentication to your web and mobile apps in under 10 minutes;*

Using Auth0, you can define, for example, a callback URL based on the user role. So you can call /owner if the user is an owner or /portalX if the user is not an owner.

This way you don't have to develop many and many security layers to secure users login.